# Microsoft.Xna.Framework for a MSVS app

Tags: visual-studio, xna

I am a psychologist, not a programmer, so I cannot figure out if the 3 warnings I am seeing when I run a MSVS application (a motion lie detection) imply I should download something or what...

Can you please see the attachment and help me understand how I should resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Your project is missing the framework.

Comment: try this framework https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20914

Comment: Thanks matty. Before I download this, I should say that I intend to learn and use Kinect soon, so I will have to download stuff for that too. Is the xna framework part of that? Related at all? Is there a single download for using the new Kinect as well as XNA? Cheers

Comment: To be honestly I only recognise the framework from an old work project. I'm not sure about the Connect and XNA library